# Creating a generic function based on these three functions in a base class without adding parameters

Tags: c#, function, selenium, generics, selenium-webdriver

I have multiple similar performing functions across many files in my project that all derive from a base class. Each of these files contains a function called IsAt() that returns a boolean based on whether I am on the correct page or not in my process. Below are some examples of the functions being used across these files..

**Example 1.**

```
public bool IsAt()
{
    try
    {
        DriverUtils.WaitTillElementVisible(_driver, ObjectRepository.H1);
    }
    catch (WebDriverTimeoutException)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (ObjectRepository.PageHeaderLocator.Text != ObjectRepository.textOnPageIdentifier) 
        return false;
    Console.WriteLine($"Login Page loaded successfully");
    return true;
}
```

**Example 2.**

```
public bool IsAt()
{
    try
    {
        DriverUtils.WaitTillElementVisible(_driver, ObjectRepository.UseAuthCodeBy);
    }
    catch (WebDriverTimeoutException)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (ObjectRepository.UseAuthCodeLocator.Text != ObjectRepository.textOnPageIdentifier) 
        return false;
    Console.WriteLine("Select two factor provider page loaded successfully!");
    return true;
}
```

**Example 3.**

```
public bool IsAt()
{
    try
    {
        DriverUtils.WaitTillElementVisible(_driver, ObjectRepository.H1);
    }
    catch (WebDriverTimeoutException)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (ObjectRepository.PageHeaderLocator.Text != ObjectRepository.TextInPageIdentifier) 
        return false;
    Console.WriteLine("Forgot password page loaded successfully");
    return true;
}
```

**The Structure:**

Based on the functions here is the structure here's how I think it would be implemented..

```
public virtual bool IsAt()
{
    OpenQA.Selenium.By obj;
    var message = "My message!";

    try
    {
        DriverUtils.WaitTillElementVisible(_driver, obj);
    }
    catch (WebDriverTimeoutException)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(obj.locator.text != obj.textOnPageIdentifier)
        return false;
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    return true;
}
```

How can I implement these functions as a single generic function? Is it possible without introducing parameters to the function? eg. `public bool IsAt(string message, obj myObject)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
//example 1
public bool IsAt()
{
    return this.IsAt(ObjectRepository.H1, ObjectRepository.PageHeaderLocator.Text, $"Login Page loaded successfully");
}

//example 2
public bool IsAt()
{
    return this.IsAt(ObjectRepository.UseAuthCodeBy, ObjectRepository.UseAuthCodeLocator.Text, "Select two factor provider page loaded successfully!");
}

//example 3
public bool IsAt()
{
    return this.IsAt(ObjectRepository.H1, ObjectRepository.PageHeaderLocator.Text, "Forgot password page loaded successfully");
}

//base class
protected bool IsAt(object element, string match, string message)
{
    try
    {
        DriverUtils.WaitTillElementVisible(_driver, element);
    }
    catch (WebDriverTimeoutException)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(match != ObjectRepository.TextInPageIdentifier)
        return false;
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    return true;
}
```